ROS2 Moveit2 Robotic arm gripper : Solution found but controller failed during execution
I have a robotic arm that I have built. The robotic arm resides inside a cylinder.  At the moment it is 100% virtual. You can find all the relevant files here: https://github.com/altijerina/agbot_arm
There is an image of the robot, as well as the rqt_graph Node Graph. I am using ROS2 on an Ubunto Humble machine, with Moveit2.
This is what happens.

I start Gazebo with no issues. Gazebo opens and I can see the robot.

I start my Controller Manager, with no problems.

Then I start the Moveit Controller Manager. RViz starts, I can see the robot arm, and I can see the Motion Planning.

I select the planning group "rail_system" to get the robot out of the cylinder. I change the Context Planning Library to "ompl", hit, Plan & Execute, and watch the robot move in Gazebo.

I select the planning group "arm", change the Context Planning Library to "ompl", hit Plan & Execute, and watch the arm move in Gazebo.

This is where the issue appears. I select the planning group "gripper", change the Context Planning Library to "ompl", hit Plan & Execute, and the movement fails.


It appears that, somehow, the gripper planning group is sending a request that the Moveit Controller is sending to the Arm Controller, rather than the Gripper Controller. I do not understand why, or how, this is happening.
Can anyone help me figure out why the gripper is not moving? I have been stuck here for a couple of weeks. Everything I have tried has, thus far, failed.
--Details of evolution--
First, I launch gazebo with: ros2 launch arm_description arm_gazebo.launch.py
Gazebo starts with no issues and the robot arm can be clearly seen in the Home position.
Then I launch my controller with : ros2 launch arm_controller controller.launch.py
At this point, I verify that my controllers are working using: ros2 control list_controllers.
Then I launch my Moveit move group controller using: ros2 launch arm_moveit arm_moveit.launch.py
There was information here but I removed it becuase this pose was too long
[moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.644043835] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
    [move_group-1] [WARN] [1727273870.644359769] [move_group]: Failed loading deceleration limits
    [move_group-1] [WARN] [1727273870.644614326] [move_group]: Failed loading deceleration limits
    [move_group-1] [WARN] [1727273870.644723234] [move_group]: Failed loading deceleration limits
    [move_group-1] [WARN] [1727273870.644958715] [move_group]: Failed loading deceleration limits
    [move_group-1] [WARN] [1727273870.645209498] [move_group]: Failed loading deceleration limits
    [move_group-1] [WARN] [1727273870.645422927] [move_group]: Failed loading deceleration limits
    [move_group-1] [WARN] [1727273870.645655649] [move_group]: Failed loading deceleration limits
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.650750528] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Available plugins: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP 
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.650841406] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.651896757] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [CIRC]
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.651922549] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.652912767] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [LIN]
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.652935111] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.653953470] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [PTP]
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.653984908] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.659261693] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'chomp'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.693210888] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'CHOMP'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715226451] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715265911] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715281372] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715351180] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'chomp.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715395083] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715409903] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715448133] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715462406] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.050000
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715475728] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715513000] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715526179] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715537023] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715547713] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715558001] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.715568496] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.844821033] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for prismatic_controller
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.848899536] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for arm_controller
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.855868941] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for gripper_controller
    [move_group-1] [ERROR] [1727273870.855952266] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: No action namespace specified for controller `gripper_action_controller` through parameter `moveit_simple_controller_manager.gripper_action_controller.action_ns`
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.856248907] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.856375212] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.857403906] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.857473073] [move_group.move_group]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.938811078] [move_group.move_group]: 
    [move_group-1] 
    [move_group-1] ********************************************************
    [move_group-1] * MoveGroup using: 
    [move_group-1] *     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
    [move_group-1] *     - ClearOctomapService
    [move_group-1] *     - CartesianPathService
    [move_group-1] *     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
    [move_group-1] *     - GetPlanningSceneService
    [move_group-1] *     - KinematicsService
    [move_group-1] *     - MoveAction
    [move_group-1] *     - MotionPlanService
    [move_group-1] *     - QueryPlannersService
    [move_group-1] *     - StateValidationService
    [move_group-1] ********************************************************
    [move_group-1] 
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.938901600] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
    [move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273870.938927084] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
    [move_group-1] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
    [move_group-1] 
    [move_group-1] You can start planning now!
    [move_group-1] 
    [rviz2-2] [ERROR] [1727273871.414264144] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273871.452303248] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273871.670160426] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.078 seconds
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273871.670251719] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'agbot_arm'...
    [rviz2-2] [WARN] [1727273872.039686807] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Group state 'gripper_ready' doesn't specify all group joints in group 'gripper'. wrist_joint is missing.
    [rviz2-2] [WARN] [1727273872.039821179] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Group state 'gripper_grab' doesn't specify all group joints in group 'gripper'. wrist_joint is missing.
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.111359026] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.114410340] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.633304873] [interactive_marker_display_99414167436800]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.684073848] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group arm
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.684123019] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.709222284] [interactive_marker_display_99414167436800]: Sending request for interactive markers
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.714490031] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm.
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.718291363] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group arm
    [rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273873.752827741] [interactive_marker_display_99414167436800]: Service response received for initialization

When I select "rail_system" from the planning group, change the planning library to "ompl", and hit Plan & Execute, the window with the Moveit Controller has the following:
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273959.791644459] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group rail_system
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273959.791788753] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'rail_system' in namespace ''
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273959.827102364] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group rail_system.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273969.445043088] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273969.445360758] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273969.445527889] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273969.445712739] [moveit_ros.plan_execution]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273969.445738244] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273969.445937495] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Starting state is just outside bounds (joint 'mid_rail_to_arm_car_joint'). Assuming within bounds.
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727273969.447648920] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request accepted
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273969.448439020] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'rail_system' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-1] [WARN] [1727273969.867073833] [moveit_trajectory_processing.time_optimal_trajectory_generation]: Joint acceleration limits are not defined. Using the default 1 rad/s^2. You can define acceleration limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.044738371] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Planning adapters have added states at index positions: [ 0 ]
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.098615603] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.098672645] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.098933734] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.099050608] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Starting trajectory execution ...
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.099141861] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.099202359] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.099521890] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: sending trajectory to prismatic_controller
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.103924465] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: prismatic_controller started execution
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727273970.103983057] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal request accepted!

I can see the rail system take the robot out of the cylinder.
Then I select the arm planning group, change the planning library to "ompl", hit "Plan & Execute" and get the following in the Moveit Window:
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274102.657380977] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group arm
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274102.657430306] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274102.690926821] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.820701546] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.821254423] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.821733413] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.821979411] [moveit_ros.plan_execution]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.822030301] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.822400001] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Starting state is just outside bounds (joint 'shoulder_joint'). Assuming within bounds.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.822542264] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Starting state is just outside bounds (joint 'elbow_joint'). Assuming within bounds.
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274108.824865324] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request accepted
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.824869273] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'arm' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.895818501] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Planning adapters have added states at index positions: [ 0 ]
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.898872956] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.898931091] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.899055229] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.899180821] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Starting trajectory execution ...
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.899243638] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.899293023] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.899522868] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: sending trajectory to arm_controller
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.901832661] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: arm_controller started execution
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274108.901966340] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal request accepted!
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274113.407860256] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Controller 'arm_controller' successfully finished
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274113.408221179] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status SUCCEEDED ...
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274113.415884403] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Solution was found and executed.
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274113.416914877] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request complete!

Here is where things go wrong. When I select "gripper" from the planning group, change the planning library to "ompl", and hit Plan & Execute, the window with the Moveit Controller has the following:
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274696.200989257] [moveit_ros_robot_interaction.robot_interaction]: No active joints or end effectors found for group 'gripper'. Make sure that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274696.203333817] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group gripper
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274696.203418026] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'gripper' in namespace ''
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274696.240315665] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group gripper.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.548785739] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.548996916] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.549119205] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.549188165] [moveit_ros.plan_execution]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.549208342] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274703.548994010] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request accepted
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.549985361] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'gripper' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.579122359] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.579178056] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.579287847] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.579434291] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Starting trajectory execution ...
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.579579807] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.579634599] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 3 controllers in list
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.579821971] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: sending trajectory to arm_controller
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.580790365] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: arm_controller started execution
[move_group-1] [WARN] [1727274703.580819200] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal request rejected
[move_group-1] [ERROR] [1727274703.581193209] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal was rejected by server
[move_group-1] [ERROR] [1727274703.581239943] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to send trajectory part 1 of 2 to controller arm_controller
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.581260051] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status ABORTED ...
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1727274703.589631697] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Solution found but controller failed during execution
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1727274703.590890836] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request aborted
[rviz2-2] [ERROR] [1727274703.591128236] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::move() failed or timeout reached

I have double, triple, and quadruple checked my joints in the Controller Manager and the Moveit Controller, as well as the URDF and anywhere else I could think of. Any help would be immensely appreciated, as I feel like I am at my wits end.
Thank you for reading this far!!!

I was able to answer this question a few hours after posting it.  It required a change to the agbot_arm/src/arm_moveit/config/agbot_arm.srdf file with regard to the gripper group.
Old Code:







New Code:




I also added a gripper kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin to the  agbot_arm/src/arm_moveit/config/kinematics.yaml  file.
